# Create an antlr3 input stream from a stringstream? (antlr3 C-target)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm currently creating an input stream from a file like this:

```
pANTLR3_UINT8 inputFile = (pANTLR3_UINT8) "X:/Path/To/File";
pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM input = antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew(inputFile);
```

However, I would like to create an input stream from a stringstream instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly possible, but you can convert the stringstream to a string and use this as input like:

```
  input = antlr3StringStreamNew((pANTLR3_UINT8)utf8.c_str(), ANTLR3_ENC_UTF8, utf8.size(), (pANTLR3_UINT8)"sql-script");
```